# Using one tableview cell to navigate to another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, picker

This may be a noob question, but honestly I can't figure it out how to create a field that will navigate you to table view controller as list picker. So this is the image,

[image: UI]

What controller should be used to create a field under "Active Client on Device" that has disclosure indicator like a table view cell? And how I trigger segue to table view controller as a list picker?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Use a `UIButton`. Call `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

Comment: @ryantxr that's what actually i do right now, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Add UIButton in cell of tableview

performSegueWithIdentifier in UIButton action method.